# Hahn-Banach theorem for separable normed spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Initially I want to clarify that the idea is to prove this theorem **without using Zorn's Lemma.** (and therefore without using the axiom of choice, since these are equivalent.)

I know this is a somewhat hackneyed question. Still, I want to present the demonstration that I have written, about which I feel there are some details to be clarified, and that is where I need the go-ahead from a second observer.

The proof of the Hanh-Banach theorem is proposed in Kreyszig's book - Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications, more precisely, it is *exercise number 9 of section 4.3, which is on page 224 of this text*. It should be noted that it is possible to use results previously demonstrated in this section of the book for the demonstration of the exercise in question.

I want to highlight that some details regarding the notation and/or nomenclature in the following sketch are subject to *theorem 4.2-1* of the book in question (*Hahn-Banach theorem. Extension of linear functionals*), which is in the page 214. I also attach the following link where you can view the text:

https://asoimatepn.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/kreyszig-erwin-introductory-functional-analysis-with-aplications-university-of-windsor-wiley-classics-library-usa-1989.pdf

**Hanh-Banach theorem (separable normed spaces.)** Let $f$ be a bounded linear functional defined in a subspace $Z$ of a separable normed space $X$. Then there exists a bounded linear functional $\widetilde{f}$ in $X$, which is an extension from $f$ to $X$ and has the same norm, $$\|\widetilde{f}\|_X=\displaystyle{\sup_{{x\in X\atop\|x\|=1}}} |\widetilde{f}(x)|, \hspace {.2cm}\|f\|_Z=\displaystyle{\sup_{{x\in X\atop\|x\|= 1}}} |f(x)|. $$
(and $ \|f\|_Z=0$ in the trivial case $ Z=\{0\}).$

***Sketch of the proof:*** Let $y_1\in X \setminus Z$. For each $c\in\mathbb{R}$ we can obtain a linear extension of $f$ to the space $Z_1$, generated by $Z$ and $\{y_1\}$ by means of $g_1(z + ay_1)=f(z)+ac$ and we can choose $c$ such that $g_1(x)\leq p(x) $ for all $ x\in Z_1$.

If $X\neq Z_1$, we can take $y_2\in X\setminus Z_1$ and repeat the process, and thus obtain an extension of $f$ to the subspace $Z_2$ generated by $Z_1$ and $\{y_2\}$, etc. Obtaining in this way a sequence of subspaces $Z_j$ such that $Z_1\subset Z_2\subset\cdots$ and such that $f$ can be extended from one to the next and the extension $g_j$ satisfies $g_j(x)\leq p(x)$ for all $x\in Z_j$.

If $X=\bigcup_{j=1}^n Z_j $ we reach the desired extension $\widetilde{f}$ in $n$ steps.

If $ X=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty Z_j $ we can use ordinary induction and get the desired result.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623210/hahn-banach-theorem-for-separable-spaces-without-zorns-lemma

Comment: (A) Of course you are using "countable choice".  Saying "we can take $y_2$..." instead of "we can choose $y_2$" does not eliminate the fact that it is a choice. Your proof may make infinitely many of these choices. (B) there is no guarantee that $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty Z_j$ is all of $X$.  Indeed there is no guarantee it is even dense in $X$.